# MOV from YMM register to RAX with intel x86-64 instructions

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, cpu-registers

I want to copy the value from YMM to RAX register, but I didn't find the correct instruction to do that. I want to do something like:

```
mov rax, ymm0
```

for example for XMM I can do: `movq rax, xmm0`. I want to something similar to this.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `vmovq rax,xmm0`. There is no corresponding instruction with an `ymm` register because the lower half of an `ymm` register is just the corresponding `xmm` register.